# Jetpack Compose : How to keep UI state across pages/composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to save the UI state of a Composable so that when switching between Composable their UI state is identical to when the view was left ?

I've tried using `rememberLazyListState()` (which uses `rememberSaveable`) to save the scroll state of a `LazyColumn` but it doesn't seems to work when coming back to the Composable.

Any ideas ?

Edit : I am using `NavController`to handle the navigation between the Composable

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out how to do it. The idea is to hoist the `LazyListState` to the Composable managing the view navigation.

```
@Composable
fun AppScreenNav(screen: Screen) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    when (screen) {
        Screen.Home -> Home()
        Screen.Favorites -> Favorites(listState)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Favorites(listState: LazyListState) {
    val favorites: List<String> by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(List(1000) { "Favorites $it" }) }
    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) {
        items(favorites) { item ->
            Text(
                color = Color.Black,
                text = item,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are hoisting the list state to the parent component. When switching between the `Home()` and `Favorites()` composable the list scrolling state should remains identical.

Comment: This isn't really a solution for complex apps. Plus you shouldn't pass a state as a parameter :(

Comment: @MSpeed What's wrong with the passing state as a parameter? The answer is a valid one.

Comment: @muthuraj https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Comment: @MSpeed Can you explain for me please :(